# Find last 3 digits before decimal point

Tags: mathematics

My old calculator only has numbers, ($+$) and ($\times $) keys 
Using only those keys, find the last three digits **precisely** before the decimal point.

### $(3 + \sqrt 7)^5$

Note: You can do the calculation without a calculator.

Comment: You could have made it a little harder by saying your calculator only has numbers and $+$, since multiplication is repeated addition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Clearly $\sqrt 7$ lies between $2.5$ and $3$. Therefore $3 - \sqrt 7 < 1/2$ and the number $(3 - \sqrt 7)^5$ will be very small indeed. We can get rid of the square roots by adding this small number, as follows:
>  $$(3 + \sqrt 7)^5 \\ \approx (3 + \sqrt 7)^5 + (3 - \sqrt 7)^5 \\= 2(3^5 + 10*3^3*7 + 5*3*7^2) \\= 2(243+1890+735) \\= 5736$$

So the actual answer is

> $5735$, or just $735$ since you only asked for three digits.

Comment: you can do slightly better than $\approx$ with $\lt$

Comment: Oh right, sorry, misunderstanding on my part. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You can determine that:

> $2.645751\lt\sqrt{7}\lt2.645752$. Both of these when added to $3$ and raised to the fifth power result in $5735.99\dots$, so the answer is $735$.